# Alignment of pgfplots inside subfloats when using tikzplotlib

Tags: pgfplots, tikzplotlib

I'm using the `tikzplotlib` code below to generate two Plots. I then place them in two subfloats. As you can see in the final latex output, the figure looks rather ugly with the two plots differently sized and not aligned.

What can i do to achieve the same size of the plots and to align them properly. Maybe worth noting, i have several of these figures with multiple subfloats in my document.

Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tikzplotlib
import numpy as np

x1=np.arange(0,10)*10e9
x2=np.arange(0,1000)
y1=np.random.randn(1,len(x1))[0]
y2=0.01*x2*np.random.randn(1,len(x2))[0]

KIT_green=(0/255,150/255,130/255)
KIT_blue=(70/255,100/255,170/255)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x2,y2,label="second trace",color=KIT_green)
plt.xlabel(r"Time $t$ (in \si{\milli\second})")
plt.ylabel(r"Amplitude $S_{11}$ \\ (some measurement) \\ (and another meaningless line) (in \si{\volt})");
tikzplotlib.save("subfigs_left.tikz",extra_axis_parameters=["ylabel style={align=center}"],axis_width="5cm",axis_height="5cm")

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x1,y1,label="first trace",color=KIT_blue)
plt.xlabel(r"Time $t$ (in \si{\milli\second})")
plt.ylabel(r"Amplitude $S_{11}$, $S_{35}$ (in \si{\volt})");
tikzplotlib.save("subfigs_right.tikz",extra_axis_parameters=["ylabel style={align=center}"],axis_width="5cm",axis_height="5cm")
```

LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \subfloat[Plot 1: this shows this]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{subfigs_left.tikz}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[Plot 2: and this shows that. But this explanation is quite long. blablabla]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{subfigs_right.tikz}}
       \caption{Two plots}
    \label{fig:subfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

The axis height and width passed from tikzplotlib to tikz refer to the axis box.  But the `\includegraphics` command's width parameter refers to the width of the entire plot, including axis labels, etc.  If you want the boxes to be the same size, use `[scale=1]` instead of `[width=0.4\textwidth]`. Aligning them vertically might be a bit trickier; I'm not familiar with subfloat.